# jQuery submit html in a form input for download as an html or doc file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header, submit

I have html stored in a hidden input on a page and I want to get the user to download it inside of an html file (or if I change the stream format to doc the html can be inside that word doc).

Is there a way jQuery can write some headers then put the html inside of the request and have a person download it?

I can then avoid submitting it to a PHP function to download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible without using flash really - unless you us base64 limited strings in links to encode it.